# less follow mode - clear screen

Tags: less

I use `less` follow mode (Shift-F) to follow a log as it is updated. Sometimes it would be useful to do some actions on my system, and then only see log output related to that action. Basically I would need some way to clear the buffer so I'm not distracted by old stuff.

I can't find anything about it on the man page, but maybe there is some trick?

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking for but could `less | grep whatyourlooking` could e a solution ?

Comment: I don't think so. Not really looking for something, just want to see the log after that action and optionally filter by /& as usual with less. Marks can solve the problem, but I would prefer just removing old stuff - then I can properly search in the newest input as well.

Comment: I got as far as `less  -C -j-1^C+G1u "`, but when I added the `F` making `less  -C -j-1^C+G1u F"`, it went wrong. The `F` repositions the page. (+1 as I want to know the answer.)

Answer (score 5):

I doubt `less` has such an option.

What you're doing is very similar to what `tail -f` achieves, only with convenient scrollback. What you can do is quit current `less` and re-launch it with

```
     tail -f logfile -n lines_back | less
```

that way your buffer will contain only `lines_back` lines of the log (and should grow just the same).

Comment: Thanks, it is not ideal but an acceptable solution

Answer (score 1):

```
less +F somelogfile
```

Any option in the COMMANDS section of the less man page can be prepended with +.  For instance, this command finds the appropriate section in the manual:

```
man less | less +/COMMANDS
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl-L to clear the terminal (on Windows/SuperPuTTY, different on Linux).

Then:

```
tail -n0 -f x.log
```

This displays a blank screen, and any new log lines will get added to the screen.

This is not `less`, but one can always run it under a different tab to retain the full power of scrollback and searching.